# Rails: Array from params is not saved in DB(Postgresql), Column is of JSONB data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to send an array of parameters from GUI to Rails controller.

I've white listed them and i could see the params carrying that array of hashes to Rails server. Issue is i don't see that column being inserted into DB.

To be precise, field `order_placed` (in this case) is skipped in Insert statement.

---

**Front end code:**

```
<table id="tabledata">
    <thead>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
        <th>Tax</th>
        <th>Discount</th>
        <th>Item Total Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="input"></tbody>
    <tbody id="template">
          <%= form_for @order do |f| %>
          <%= f.label :ordertype %>
          <%= f.text_field :ordertype %> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

          <%= f.label :totalprice %>
          <%= f.text_field :totalprice %> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

          <%= f.label :paymentmethod %>
          <%= f.text_field :paymentmethod %>

          <br>

        <tr>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][itemname]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][quantity]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][unitprice]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][tax]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][discount]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][itemtotalprice]" type="text" /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][itemname]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][quantity]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][unitprice]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][tax]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][discount]" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input name="orderplaced[][itemtotalprice]" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
<label id="ActionAddRow">Add Row</label>
<%= f.submit %>
 <% end %>
```

---

**Controller Code:**

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @order=Order.new
    end

    def create
        @order=Order.new(order_params)
        @order.customer=Customer.first
        @order.save
    end

    private
        def order_params
            params.require(:order).permit(:ordertype, :totalprice, :paymentmethod, order_placed: [:itemname, :quantity, :unitprice, :tax, :discount, :itemtotalprice])

        end
end
```

---

**Server Side issue:**

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-07 12:26:09 +0530
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"order"=>{"ordertype"=>"Home delivery", "totalprice"=>"10", "paymentmethod"=>"Cash"}, "utf8"=>"Γ£ô", "authenticity_token"=>"BFl2CfwytjM48bHIIUsrjNqk8bU75CHx/V3TH0OlviGabNmxDd3HXuhK0xHKHJwvbNvgD8Hivf62PYwFPDIIag==", "orderplaced"=>[{"itemname"=>"Laptop", "quantity"=>"1", "unitprice"=>"10", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"10"}, {"itemname"=>"Cable", "quantity"=>"0", "unitprice"=>"0", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"0"}], "commit"=>"Create Order"}
  Customer Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" ORDER BY "customers"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("ordertype", "totalprice", "paymentmethod", "created_at", "updated_at", "customer_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["ordertype", "Home delivery"], ["totalprice", 10.0], ["paymentmethod", "Cash"], ["created_at", "2018-01-07 06:56:10.053668"], ["updated_at", "2018-01-07 06:56:10.053668"], ["customer_id", 1]]
   (1.3ms)  COMMIT
```

---

field `order_placed` which contains array of hashes in params `"orderplaced"=>[{"itemname"=>"Laptop", "quantity"=>"1", "unitprice"=>"10", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"10"}, {"itemname"=>"Cable", "quantity"=>"0", "unitprice"=>"0", "tax"=>"0", "discount"=>"0", "itemtotalprice"=>"0"}]` is skipped in Insert statement. This is expected to be saved in DB in order_placed field of JSONB data type.

Comment: You've permited `order_placed` and `orderplaced` it's different attributes.

Comment: Thank you Зелёный. This helped me in resolving my issue in conjunction to @Daniel's comment.

Comment: It is not an issue, it is a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><input name="orderplaced[][itemname]" type="text" /></td>
```

Put order in the name attribute.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This helped me in resolving the issue in conjunction to the above comment.